# Python TesseractError : can't find components in /usr/local/share/tessdata/eng.traineddata

Tags: python, macos, tesseract

I get an error when I write the following code :

```
img = cv2.imread(path)

#adding custom options
custom_config = r'--oem 2 --psm 6'
pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config=custom_config)
```

HERE is the error :

```
TesseractError: (1, "Error: Tesseract (legacy) engine requested, but components are not present in /usr/local/share/tessdata/eng.traineddata!! Failed loading language 'eng' Tesseract couldn't load any languages! Could not initialize tesseract.")
```

I need some help please (I'm on **mac**).

Answer (score 1):

That means your `eng.traineddata` has only new (LSTM) engine, but you asked tesseract to use legacy engine (`--oem 2`). Download and install `eng.traineddata` that has also components with legacy engine.